# How to rotate bi_server.out log file

Tags: oracle12c, obiee

Oracle OBIEE 12c. We have log rotation set up for the bi_server logs. They are set to 5MB, and rotate accordingly.  However, we have a log file called bi_server.out which is 24GB and doesn't rotate for some reason.  I don't see any settings in the WLS Admin Console to change the rotation settings for this log file.

Hoping someone could tell me where to look for the settings of this specific log to ensure that it rotates at a certain size, or creates a new log beyond logging so many queries.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

.out isn't technically one of the log files which are governed by the log rotation. The .out is the file where the detailed outputs get piped to.

Update: If your .out file grows to those sizes then you definitely have an issue somewhere. You have to find out what's duping into the .out all the time and why.

Rename the file to bi_server1_0001.out when the obis1 component is stopped and then the system will create a new, empty one.

Comment: Any thoughts on where this might be setup or configured?